# How to add new column to dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do this and I get a long error:

```
df=df.withColumn('NewColumnName', someother_df['Time'])
```

and it doesn't work. 
also doing this:

```
df=df.withColumn('NewColumnName', someother_df.select('Time'))
```

gives me this error: AssertionError: col should be Column